# How to fix 'The provided key element does not match the schema' error?

Tags: javascript, database, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB for my application and I need to get some items that match one of the keys in an array, this is my code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

try {
    const IDs = 
    [
        {"profileID": {"S": "my_first_id"}}, 
        {"profileID": {"S": "my_second_id"}}
    ]

    const postsResult = await db.batchGetItem({
      RequestItems: {
        'Feed': {
          Keys: IDs
        }
      }
    }).promise();
    

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(postsResult),
    };
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return { error: err }
}
 }
```

But I get this error:

> The provided key element does not match the schema

And this is the schema:

```
type Feed @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private}]){
  profileID: String @index(name: "feedByProfileID")
  type: String
  postID: String
  shareID: String
  likeID: String
  commentID: String
  replyID: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is you are trying to do a `BatchGetItem` on a Global Secondary Index (GSI) which is not possible, this is because items in a GSI are not required to be unique, however, they are required to be unique for `GetItem` and `BatchGetItem`.

You can do one of 2 things:

1. Send multiple `Query` calls
2. Send a PartiQL `ExecuteStatement` call

```
// Declare function
const exStatement = statement => {
  db.executeStatement({
    Statement: statement
  })
    .promise() // Promise
    .then(res => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res)) 
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err)) 
}

//Call function
exStatement(`SELECT * from "Feed"."feedByProfileID" where profileID IN ['my_first_id','my_second_id']`) // Up to 50 PK's
```